# How to manage count on badges when some data get from api in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to manage count on badges when some data get from api in Flutter? such as when a new message or data is received, count on the badges changes.

I use Badges Package for displaying Icon and count on badges in my apps https://pub.dev/packages/badges

Comment: It is not about updating badges count. It is about stream listening from your api? Could you get all data real time insert to list then setState to your widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use Getx state management system for that.

by default you have to put value of badge  = 0;

after whenever you call the api just give the incoming value to getx variable, and give badge value like this:

badgeContent: incoming_value == null ? Text("0") : Text(incoming_value)

Comment: Is there any specific reason to mention getX here ? @Tanya-error didn't asked how to do that using state management. It can be simply be done using setstate or any state management pattern.

Comment: getx is most favourite package in pub.dev. and most likely also. so i prefer @Tanya-error to do it with getx.

Comment: No doubt getX is very popular now days but the question is not about state management pattern. You can't impost your favourite package to other person.

Comment: hi thanks for the information. can you give a simple example to solve this problem wit GetX ?